# Convert Alphanumerical Date String to Numerical Date String

Tags: python, date, datetime, datetime-format

I know there are similar questions out there, but most simply convert the alphanumerical date string to a `datetime` object with the `strptime` method, which is not what I'm going for. All I'm trying to do is convert string like so.

**Format of Possible Input**

```
December 7, 2015
October 24, 2018
```

**Desired Output**

```
2015-12-07
2018-10-24
```

**How I've Gone About It**

```
""" funding_expiration[0] is equal to strings like 'December 7, 2015' """
funding_expiration = funding_expiration[0].text.split()
""" still need to convert Month (%B) to ## (%m) """
funding_expiration[1] = funding_expiration[1].replace(',', '')
# add padding to single digit days
if len(funding_expiration[1]) is 1:
    funding_expiration[1] = funding_expiration[1].zfill(1)
# format numerical date string
funding_expiration = funding_expiration[2] + '-' + funding_expiration[0] + '-' + funding_expiration[1]
```

I'm still trying to figure out an efficient way to convert the full name of months into their corresponding numerals. I'm new to Python, so I'm wondering whether or not there's a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: @Sarcoma sorry, what do you mean? i don't care if it is the code above or some other code. however, i'd rather not create a dict since this is literally the only time i'll ever need to do this

Comment: @Sarcoma yes, id rather not use a library since this is literally the only time in the entire script that ill need to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.strptime` can work in your case too. You can use the `%B` directive to parse full month names.

```
import datetime

s = 'December 7, 2015'

date_string = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%B %d, %Y').date())

>>> date_string
'2015-12-07'
```

Comment: perfect. thanks. as soon as it lets me, ill mark this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using 3rd party `dateutil`:

```
from dateutil import parser

L = ['December 7, 2015', 'October 24, 2018']

res_str = [parser.parse(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in L]

['2015-12-07', '2018-10-24']
```

Comment: not really fond of using a framework since ill only ever need to do this once in the entire script. ive also imported `datetime` for something else, so...